# SWIFT: Adjust UIStackView to the width of the button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIStackView component in which I have added two buttons. The buttons clickable area seems to be fully adjusted to the length of the button. However, the Subviews in which I am adding these buttons is not adjusted to just fit the button area. The first button never fits because the text is too short.

[image]

As you can see on above screenshot, the first button has tons of space between the button itself and the SubView. This will do more what I am looking for if the text on the first button was longer, but per requirements, the text will be short.

This is the code I am using right now to add my buttons into the UIStackView.

```
private let horizontalStackview: UIStackView = {
        let horizontalStackview = UIStackView()
        horizontalStackview.axis = .horizontal
        horizontalStackview.distribution = .fill
        horizontalStackview.alignment = .center
        horizontalStackview.addArrangedSubview(self.button)
        horizontalStackview.addArrangedSubview(self.anotherLongButton)
        return horizontalStackview
    }()
```

How can I configure my stackView to avoid the gaps between the Button and the StackView subview? Nothing I tried with the horizontalStackview properties seem to work.

Comment: Are you using `Autolayout`?

Comment: You mean `Autolayout` on my UIStackView component? I don't think so, I am just using what I have described above in my question. Is there anything I could add?

Comment: It's evident that you aren't using storyboards, so it would be great if you can add more context, like the constraints or the frames you have set. This doesn't provide enough info for anyone to pinpoint what's wrong

Comment: @user3587624 - you need to show the code you are using to add `horizontalStackview` to your view.